# break string and arrays down intro separate items

Tags: python, arrays, file, python-3.x, tuples

I have data in a file that has two sets of values and then an unspecified series of arrays
(each with 3 sub items in them)

For example:

```
('January', 2, [('curly', 30), ('larry',10), ('moe',20)])
```

I need the data read and present back and partially re-assign the data to new variables.

For example:

```
Month: January
Section: 3 
curly has worked 30 hours 
larry has worked 10 hours 
moe has worked 20 hours
```

I can get the first two parts of the string read, *but don't know how to break the arrays down* - each file may have different numbers of sub arrays, so need to do as while loop?

```
import ast 

filecontent = ast.literal_eval(filename.read())

for item in filecontent:
    month = filecontent[0]
    section = filecontent[1]

    name1 = filecontent[2] # not working
    hours1 = filecontent[3]# not working
    name2 = filecontent[4]# not working
    hours2 = filecontent[5]# not working
    # account for additional arrays somehow?

print ("month:" + month)
print ("section" + str (section))
print (str (name1) + "has worked"  + str (hours1))
print (str (name2) + "has worked"  + str (hours2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to store your workers.
**Edit**

```
work = [('January', 2, [('curly', 30, 5), ('larry',10, 5), ('moe',20, 10)])]

workers = dict()
month = ""
section = ""
for w in work:
    month = w[0]
    section = w[1]
    for worker, time, overtime in w[2]:
        workers[worker] = (time, overtime)
    print "Month: {0}\nSection: {1}".format(month, section)
    print "".join("%s has worked %s hours, overtime %s\n" % (worker, time[0], time[1]) for worker, time in workers.items())
```

Comment: I've adapted your code into my solution (below), but have one new array element to add.

Comment: Almost perfect, but I need to work a third array item in now.
See new posting below...

Comment: In the edit code i'm adding the second and third items of the array as a tuple into the right worker index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the third item in the sequence.

```
for item in filecontent:
    print 'Month %s' % item[0]
    print 'Section %d' % item[1]

    for name, hours in item[2]:
        print "%s has worked %d hours" % (name, hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate filecontent with item but you don't use item at all. I think there is one mistake. Maybe you should use item[0] instead of filecontent[0], item[1] instead of filecontent[1] and so on

Answer (score 0):

Just as justin suggested, you have to iterate over the third item in filecontent: i.e. iterate over filecontent[2]

Comment: Ultimately, I need to preform calculations on the data, so thought about assigning variables to the separate elements.  (i.e I need a way to distinguish between the array items - [Name1, Hours1]  [Name2, Hours2] and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

I now need to figure out how to read and process an additional item in the array.
A new figure for a bonus for example

filecontent = [('January', 2, [('curly', 30, **5**), ('larry',10, **5**), ('moe',20, **10**)])]

The code below works fine as it stands, and allows the user to make calculations
based on the data.  I need the third figure adding now. Then project complete.

```
filecontent = [('January', 2, [('curly', 30), ('larry',10), ('moe',20)])]

staff = dict()

for item in filecontent:
    month = filecontent[0]
    section = filecontent[1]

    for name, hours in filecontent[2]:
        staff[name] = hours

print ("month:" + month)
print ("section: " + str (section))

print ("".join("%s has worked %s hours\n" % (name, hours) for name, hours in staff.items()))

overtime = int(input ("Enter overtime figure: "))

print ("".join("%s has now worked %s hours \n" % (name, (hours + overtime)) for name, hours in staff.items()))
```

I have tried this;

```
staff = dict()

for item in filecontent:
    month = filecontent[0]
    section = filecontent[1]

    for name, hours, bonus in filecontent[2]:
        staff[name] = hours, bonus

print ("month:" + month)
print ("section: " + str (section))

print ("".join("%s has worked %s hours with %s bonus \n" % (name, hours, bonus) for name, hours, bonus in staff.items()))
```